# Ruby methods for element reference and assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, code-documentation

I'm reading the docs for Ruby 2.5.0 and I don't understand this part about the Methods:

> Additionally, methods for element reference and assignment may be
>   defined: [] and []= respectively. Both can take one or more arguments,
>   and element reference can take none.

```
class C
  def [](a, b)
    puts a + b
  end

  def []=(a, b, c)
    puts a * b + c
  end
end

obj = C.new

obj[2, 3]     # prints "5"
obj[2, 3] = 4 # prints "10"
```

1) Why and how the assignment method in this case assigns a=2 b=3 and c=4?

2) Seems that it behaves like the method for element reference, so if this is the case, why does it exist? I could just write:

```
def [](a, b, c)
        puts a * b + c
end
obj[2, 3, 4] # prints "10"
```

and it wouldn't change anything, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why and how the assignment method in this case assigns a=2 b=3 and c=4?

`a`, `b`, and `c` are the *parameters* and `2`, `3`, and `4` are the arguments. Arguments are bound to parameters just like every other method, because `[]=` *is* a method just like every other method.

> 2) Seems that it behaves like the method for element reference, so if this is the case, why does it exist? I could just write: […]

You could also just write `obj.foo(2, 3, 4)` or `obj.frobnicate(2, 3, 4)` or `obj.(2, 3, 4)`. It doesn't matter. It's just a method like any other, and `[]=` is just a name like any other. You could also write it

```
obj.[]=(2, 3, 4)
```

if you want.

The name doesn't matter. (To a computer, anyway.)

Except the name *does* matter! (Method) names are what we use to communicate the intent of our code to our (human) colleagues.

So, `[]` and `[]=` are different names, and they communicate different intent. In particular, `[]` communicates the intent to *get* something and `[]=` communicates the intent to *set* something. Note, however, that the examples in the documentation purely demonstrate how arguments are bound for indexer and indexing assignment methods, they are *not* good examples of how to use such methods; maybe that is part of the source of your confusion. A much better example is how the `[]` and `[]=` methods are used by the `Array` and `Hash` classes.

Note also that "the name doesn't matter" is slightly exaggerated. The name *does* matter because of the fact that Ruby allows you to write

```
obj[2, 3] = 4
```

instead of

```
obj.[]=(2, 3, 4)
```

which would be the "normal" syntax for a message send to a method named `[]=`. `[]=` is one of a set of methods that have *syntactic sugar* allowing them to be called in a non-standard way. Other such methods are `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<<`, `>>`, `|`, `&` etc. which can be called like `a + b` instead of `a.+(b)`, `!`, `+@`, `-@`, which can be called as `!a`, `+a`, and `-a` instead of `a.!`, `a.+@`, and `a.-@`, `call` which can be called like `a.(1, 2)` instead of `a.call(1, 2)`, and any method ending with `=` which can be called like `a.foo = 42` instead of `a.foo=(42)`. (And some others as well.)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I didn't read yet that some methods could be called in a non-standard way, now I understand why it behaves that way, also your explanation about when to use [] or []= is what I was missing, thanks again.